# MvvmLight and CustomMessageBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, messagebox, silverlight-toolkit, cimbalino

Is there a proper mvvm way to show CustomMessageBox from the view and get callback from it?

[This](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eladkatz/archive/2011/02/06/mvvm-how-to-show-a-dialog-box-from-the-viewmodel-using-behaviors.aspx) sample is quite nice, but it uses hardcoded MessageBoxButton (only Yes/No/YesNo are avaivable, but i need custom buttons).

[This](http://hintdesk.com/c-mvvmlight-toolkit-messages/) contains lots ofuseful info about Messages in MvvmLight, but DialogMessage is also showing only YesNo sample (also no custom buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that [Cimbalino toolkit](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit/blob/master/src/Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit%20%28WP71%29/Services/MessageBoxService.cs) (Cimbalino saves the day again!) has quite nice custom messagebox.

Comment: [This one](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/coding4fun-wp7-message-prompt-in-depth) is also a way.